# JavaScript function to hide/unhide panel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I'm using asp.net(C#) under visual studio 2010

I have a panel that is by default set 2 be hidden( visible=false)

I need to create a JavaScript function that would be executed on a button click to make this panel visible if hidden and hidden if visible.
and this should be client side, here is the code I have so far

```
   <script type=text/javascript>

    function func1()
    {
    i need this code please
    }

<asp:Panel ID="ResultsPanel" runat="server">

Some controls

</asp:Panel>

<asp:button id=button1 runat=server onclick=javascript:func1()>Hide/Unhide</asp:button>
```

Comment: If you set visible=false, the panel will not show up in your DOM, and can not be set visible later. You should have visible=true, and then hide it with CSS (style="display:none"), and then show it with one of the below solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you may make use of following jQuery methods,

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 4):

first you need to use `OnClientClick` attribute instead of `OnClick` for your button, and if that button does not run any server side code you can use html button instead of `asp:Button`

```
 <input type="button" onclick="func1();" value="Hide/Unhide">
```

you can use `toggle` function in `jquery` to hide/unhide your panel

```
function func1()
{
   var mypanel = $('#<%=ResultsPanel.ClientID%>');
   mypanel.toggle();
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mpLNQ/)**

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var Panel = document.getElementById("ResultsPanel");
if (Panel.style.display == "block" || Panel.style.display == "")
{
    Panel.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
    Panel.style.display = "block";
}
```